# Assigning if-else statement into a variable in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new in Python and I have a question. Is this possible to assign if-else statement into a variable in the same line? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Python has conditional expressions, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/3001761.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Python's *conditional expression* :

```py
a = 1
even = 'true' if a%2==0 else 'false'
```

You'll find the official documentation for conditional expression [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Answer (score -1):

In python,`lambda function`.
this is example how you can use it.

```
max = lambda a, b : a if(a > b) else b
 
print(max(1, 2))
print(max(10, 2))

#output:
#2
#10
```